# Location pointing in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have displayed the google map and pointed the required location by giving the latitude and longitude. There is no issue in that. But while loading the map it shows some other place and i am supposed to drag to find my pin pointed location. Is there any way to directly display the pointed location on screen instead of dragging the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your `Camera` by using `.animateCamera()` to that particular **Location** like

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            latitude, longitude), 18.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
public void animateCameraTo(final double lat, final double lng)
{
    _googleMap = getMap();
    CameraPosition camPosition = _googleMap.getCameraPosition();
    if (!((Math.floor(camPosition.target.latitude * 100) / 100) == (Math.floor(lat * 100) / 100) && (Math.floor(camPosition.target.longitude * 100) / 100) == (Math.floor(lng * 100) / 100)))
    {
        _googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        _googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)), new CancelableCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                _googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                _googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Let me know if you need more help from my side for same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
    zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    mv.moveCamera(center);
    mv.animateCamera(zoom);
```